# emberjs action event.target is undefined

Tags: ember.js

Here's a link to a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qt972/

When you run the fiddle you'll see a name and a button to make the "person" say hello. This works fine, however the "event" is undefined.

An even simpeler case also fails:

http://jsfiddle.net/CCg2K/1/

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: For the purpose of consistency I think you should update your fiddle's to use specific version 0.9.5 of ember and not ember-latest, since the code in your examples will actually work with the next release of ember :) . See the UPDATE in my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do a `console.log(arguments)` inside your action callback you can see that there are actually 3 parameters passed. The first one is the view, the second is the event and the third is the context.

You can rewrite your edit action like this:

```
edit: function(view, event, context) {
  var target = event.target;
  ...
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: since commit [657a2664](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/657a2664347b9a4f0ef01a96ad2adc30ba51a0f0) - available in release `0.9.6` I guess - only a single `event` parameter is passed which has the view and context as properties. So if you want to access those you have to do the following:

```
edit: function(event) {
  var view = event.view;
  var context = event.context;
  ...
}
```

Comment: console.log(arguments) I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, Ember.js version 0.9.6 has been released https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/9b9f40f7d4b95a2b19b3f01e7a8391b873746201