# Emberjs after change content events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Feature:
After add a new *"tab"* could action the alert event like the default ones.

Idea:

- Create a `TabsController`
- Create a `initilizerView`  and use a list parameter for handle the `TabsController.Content`
- WHEN the view *"didInsertElement"*, it add the action alert event to the defaults content 
  BUT if I add a new one I dont know how to action again this `function ( "didInsertElement" )`

Help please

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/chalien/Hxste/2/

**solved by pangratz**
Thanks for your help and refactor :)

http://jsfiddle.net/chalien/Hxste/

Comment: I added "jquery" tag to this question, as it is JQuery related.

Comment: @MikeAski if you are giving edit suggestions, it would be be nice to keep them substantial and improve other things like formatting spelling etc **also** in the post :)

Comment: thnks @MikeAski i'm a stackoverflow newbie

Comment: If you got an answer to your question, please make sure you'll accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `action` Handlebars helper, see http://jsfiddle.net/jmDXP/

**Handlebars:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="mainview" >
    {{#each list}}
    <div {{action "clicked"}} >{{title}} / {{desc}}</div>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    <div id="container"></div>
    {{#view App.TabView}}
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="title"}}
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="desc"}}
        <button {{action "addTab" }} >Add</button>
    {{/view}}
</script>
​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var get = Ember.get;

App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Tab = Ember.Object.extend({
    title: null,
    desc: null
});

App.TabsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    resourceType: App.Tab,
    addTab: function(title, desc) {
        this.pushObject(App.Tab.create({
            title: title,
            desc: desc
        }));
    },
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            this.addTab("hola" + i, "test " + i);
        }
    }
});

App.TabView = Ember.View.extend({
    addTab: function() {
        var title = get(this, 'title');
        var desc = get(this, 'desc');
        App.TabsController.addTab(title, desc);
    }
});

App.initializeView = Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'mainview',
    listBinding: 'App.TabsController',
    clicked: function(view, event, context) {
        console.log('clicked @', get(context, 'title'));
    }
});

App.initializeView.appendTo('#container');​
```

Note: in the upcoming version the arguments of an `action` callback changed, see [emberjs action event.target is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530912/emberjs-action-event-target-is-undefined)

Comment: Thanks for your refactor and your solution. that was really useful for me THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace:

```
$(".test").click(function(){
```

by:

```
$(".test").on('click', function(){
```

which will register the handler for all present & future matching elements...

More info @ http://api.jquery.com/on/