# Best way to store "temp" data on an ember button

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.Button which should remove an element from an array. The button label is simply an X (for now).

I'd like to know the best way to store data for use by the button. If this was plain jquery I might use data-username. But what's the best way to do this?

**update**
Use case for this question would be something like this:

```
{{#each App.recentUsersArray}}
    <li>
        {{#view App.RecentNameBtn contentBinding="this"}} {{content}} {{/view}}
        {{#view App.RecentNameDeleteBtn}}X{{/view}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

In the second view, I need a way to know which username the delete action should apply to.

Comment: are you looking for something like session on a client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `{{action}}` helper, which passes the context as argument, see http://jsfiddle.net/zVd9g/. Note: in the upcoming Ember.js version the action helper only passes one argument so you would have to adapt your sources [accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530912/emberjs-action-event-target-is-undefined/9531655#9531655).

If you want to use your existing views, you could do a `contentBinding="this"` on the `App.RecentNameDeleteBtn` as you already did on the `App.RecentNameBtn`.

**Handlebars:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#each App.arrayController}}
        <button {{action "showTweets" target="App.arrayController" }} >{{this}}</button>
        <button {{action "removeItem" target="App.arrayController" }}>x</button>
        <br/>            
    {{/each}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.arrayController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    removeItem: function(view, evt, item) {
        console.log('remove user %@'.fmt(item));
        this.removeObject(item);
    },
    showTweets: function(view, evt, item) {
        console.log('show tweets of user %@'.fmt(item));
    }
});​
```

Comment: Couple of questions.

1) What's .fmt? Is that a binding to %@ in your console.log statement? Where's that documented?

2) The action "showTweets". That just calls the method on the object containing the items correct?

Comment: By the way, this definitely is better than using Button. I love that action passed the current item in the loop, automatically.

Comment: `fmt` is a helper for formatting strings. See my blog post http://code418.com/blog/2012/03/08/useful-emberjs-functions/ and have a look at the code https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/3b60016c2b6b38646d954014d10f74fcfe1a3d54/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/string.js#L49-57

Comment: Oh that's awesome! I up voted your answer AND the previous comment. Thanks Clemens!